How to tigger new state from Consumer result using BloC
I am currently stuck with the consumption of a new value coming from a Provider.Consumer
Requirement:
Trigger new server call to get new data, refresh UI after coming back from SettingsPage
on my HomePage I am getting all the available strings given the languageCode using a BloC object, this language code I am reading from a LanguageProvider class that pretty much notifies changes in the sharedPreferences.
Here is my consumer part,
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<LanguageProvider>(
        builder: (context, languageProvider, child) {
      return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => HomePageBloc(
          getTerms: context.read<GetAllTerms>(),
          languageProvider: languageProvider,
        )..add(const FetchTopicsEvent()),
        child: const _Content(),
      );
    });
  }
}

HomePageBloc
class HomePageBloc extends Bloc<HomePageEvent, HomePageState> {
  HomePageBloc({
    required GetAllTerms getTerms,
    required LanguageProvider languageProvider,
  })  : _getAllTerms = getTerms,
        _languageProvider = languageProvider,
        super(const HomePageState()) {
    on<FetchTopicsEvent>(
      _fetchTopics,
      transformer: throttleDroppable(const Duration(milliseconds: 100)),
    );
  }

  final GetAllTerms _getAllTerms;
  final LanguageProvider _languageProvider;

  Future<void> _fetchTopics(event, Emitter<HomePageState> emit) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: HomePageStatus.loading));
    final list = await _getAllTerms(_languageProvider.getPrefLanguageCode());

    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        status: HomePageStatus.success,
        terms: list,
      ),
    );
  }
}

So far, the consumer bloc is being called every time I update the language preference from Settings and the bloc is being attached but it doesn't go inside the method _fetchTopics again, so there is no new state produced from my BloC.
Expectation:
UI should refresh on consumer block

If your HomePageState has no other state than the data fetched in _fetchTopics, you can simply use BlocProvider.value
return BlocProvider.value(
  value: HomePageBloc(
    getTerms: context.read<GetAllTerms>(),
    languageProvider: languageProvider,
  )..add(const FetchTopicsEvent()),
  child: const _Content(),
)

Otherwise to keep the additional state, you need subscribe to an update stream using emit.forEach in _fetchTopics
